# Android app communicate over server with other phones

Tags: android, sockets, server, nfc

So i wanna make an android app, where when i scan an nfc tag, a signal gets sent to my server, and then to all other phones with that specific app. I dont know where to start and would like recommendations on what to use for that.

If someone would be able to help, id be glad!

Comment: I think Firebase real-time database and Firestore would be helpful for you.

Comment: What server do you have to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

You can use cloud messaging options:

- [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging)
- [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/)

You can also implement [MQTT](https://mqtt.org/) and show notifications yourself